# jQuery capture ID of clicked element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to capture the ID of the element being clicked when a user clicks on an element which allows him to leave a page. The idea is to then record this using Ajax. The script below seems to be working fine as long as the element has an ID, but it does not seem to be able to climb the DOM to find an ancestor's ID if it has not. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a, button, input[type=submit]').on('click', function (event) {
        if (event.target.id == '')
            alert($(this).closest('[id!=""]').attr('id'));

        else
            alert(event.target.id);
    });
});
```

Comment: The code works fine here, http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/bg91uqpm/ maybe its how your binding the event

Comment: @Brian it doesn't work correctly if the id attribute is not present on the clicked element as the code only checks for an empty string

Comment: @Brian yes but remove the id from an element and it will return undefined. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bg91uqpm/3/) the last button

Comment: Ah ok :) thanks for clearing that up for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the parent's id is not defined or the element is nested so much that you can't count how many parents it has, i.e. get the closest parent's id that actually has an id, then this code will do the job for you: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/54r4zzu8/2/)**

```
$(document).on('click', 'a, button, [type="submit"]', function() {

    if($(this).attr('id') === undefined || $(this).attr('id') === null) {
        alert($(this).parents().filter(function(){
            return $(this).attr('id')!=undefined && $(this).attr('id')!=null;
        }).attr('id'));
    } else {
         alert($(this).attr('id')); 
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would recursively find the **IDs**

```
$(document).on('click', 'a, button, [type="submit"]', function() {

    findID($(this));

});

function findID(element) {
    if(element.attr('id') === undefined || element.attr('id') === null) {
        var temp = element.parent().attr('id');
        if(temp === undefined || temp === null){
            findID(element.parent());
        } else {
           alert(temp);
        }
    } else {
         alert(element.attr('id')); 
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/54r4zzu8/4/)

Comment: what if the parent element doesn't have an id either?

Comment: Then you have to recursively parse the DOM element using a function. But I believe that is out of scope for this question.

Comment: On the contrary, I believe that is exactly what the OP is asking for, to find the closest container with an id so there's actually something to log

Comment: @koala_dev check out my answer to see the fix of that problem

Comment: @koala_dev Please find the answer on recursively finding the **IDs**

Answer (score 1):

Here a way to look recursively through the DOM for an ID attribut:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a, button, input[type=submit]').on('click', function (event) {               
            getID($(this));
        });

        function getID(element) {
            if (element.attr('id') && element.attr('id') !== "") {
                alert(element.attr('id'));
            } else if (element.parent()) {
                getID(element.parent());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The issues with your code is that you're only checking if the id attribute of the clicked element is empty but you're not checking if it's actually present. Also it seems that the `[id!=""]` selector is not working correctly but I found that adding `[id]` before to force the element to have an id makes it work, so the more concise solution would be this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a, button, input[type=submit]').on('click', function () {
        var id = this.id ? this.id : $(this).closest('[id][id!=""]').attr('id');
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/70vfkupp/3)**